# How to declare an 2d array pointer of fixed size elements

Tags: c, arrays

I wanted to declare an 2d array in a header file such as;

```
char ar[][4];
```

So the array has no decided number of elements known before the program is run (But the length of each element is known). But I can't use malloc here because `ar` is declared this way.

So I tried this;

```
char* ar[4];
```

But this only gives an array of 4 pointers (not my goal).

Do I have to use `char**` or there is another workaround that I can use to declare the length of each element ?

Comment: Can you elaborate `I can't use malloc here because ar is declared this way` ?

Answer (score 0):

Declaring something like

```
char ar[][4];
```

is typically met with a compiler error such as

```
'ar': unknown size
```

because fixed arrays must have a defined size at compile time.

For an array to have its size defined during run-time you must use dynamic allocation.

Here's a very simple example.

```
char** alloc2dArray(const int rows, const int rowlen) {
    // allocate the array of rows.
    size_t size = rows * sizeof(char*);
    char** pptr = (char**)malloc(size);

    // allocate the rows.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        pptr[i] = (char*)malloc(rowlen);
    }
    return pptr;
}

void free2dArray(char** pptr, const int rows) {
    // free the rows
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
        free(pptr[i]); 
    // free array of rows
    free(pptr);
}
```

And note with pointer-to-pointer you get square bracket sugar

```
const int rows = 7;
const int rowlen = 4;
char** arr = alloc2dArray(rows, rowlen);    
char c = '@';
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {    
    int j = 0;
    for (; j < rowlen; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = c++;
    }   
}
free2dArray(arr, rows);
```